# iOS: Firebase Storage set timeout

Tags: ios, swift3, firebase-storage

when downloading from storage, I would like to set a smaller timeout, e.g. only 5 - 10 seconds, is this possible?

I'm downloadiung like this:

```
        let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: "gs://...")
        let fileRef = storageRef.child(myLink)
        let downloadTask = fileRef.write(toFile: url) { url, error in
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make a extension to the StorageDownloadTask class and add a function that sets a timer with the requested time that cancels the request if fired.

Something like this:

```
extension StorageDownloadTask {
func withTimout(time: Int, block: @escaping () -> Void) {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: TimeInterval(time), repeats: false) { (_) in
        self.cancel()
        block()
    }
}
```

So you would write:

```
fileRef.write(toFile: url, completion: {
    (url, error) in
    ...
}).withTimeout(time: 10) {
    //Here you can tell everything that needs to know if the download failed that it did
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`FIRStorage` (renamed `Storage`) now proposes timeout variables you can use:

```
let storage = Storage.storage()
storage.maxUploadRetryTime = 10
storage.maxOperationRetryTime = 10
storage.maxDownloadRetryTime = 10
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`Firebase Storage` has a feature where you can `pause()`, `cancel()`, and `resume()` read [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#manage_uploads)

I would set a class property  as  `StorageUploadTask` then I would put the pause or cancel in a `DispatchAsync Timer` using a `DispatchWorkItem`:

```
// 1. make sure you `import Firebase` to have access to the `StorageUploadTask`
import Firebase

var timeoutTask: DispatchWorkItem?
var downloadTask: StorageUploadTask?

// using your code from your question
let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: "gs://...")
let fileRef = storageRef.child(myLink)

// 2. this cancels the downloadTask
timeoutTask = DispatchWorkItem{ [weak self] in
          self?.downloadTask?.cancel()
}

// 3. this executes the code to run the timeoutTask in 5 secs from now. You can cancel this from executing by using timeoutTask?.cancel() 
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5, execute: timeoutTask!)

// 4. this initializes the downloadTask with the fileRef your sending the data to
downloadTask = fileRef.write(toFile: url) { 
          (url, error) in

          self.timeoutTask?.cancel() 
          // assuming it makes it to this point within the 5 secs you would want to stop the timer from executing the timeoutTask

          self.timeoutTask = nil // set to nil since it's not being used
 }
```

Unfortunately Firebase doesn't have this feature available for the `RealTimeDatabase`