# Firebase iOS: StorageReference.putData is stuck when no network connection is available?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload some data to Firebase Storage using the following code. However, if no internet connection is available, the call seems to be stuck. I suppose I could set a timer and cancel the task after a timeout. However, it's not an elegant solution. The upload could take a long time. It's also not right to check for internet connection before the call. Just because I have internet doesn't mean I can connect to Firebase.

```
let storageRef = firebaseStorage.reference(withPath: path)
storageRef.putData(data, metadata: metadata) { metadata, error in
    ...  // This never gets called if there's no internet connection

}
```

Does anyone have a reasonable solution to the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43385122/ios-firebase-storage-set-timeout

Comment: Thanks! it seems that there really isn't an elegant solution then.